# What are all the forms of instantaneous galactic travel in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek

With the release of [Star Trek Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery), non-warp travel in the [Star Trek universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek) has become a topical issue. I'm not aware of all the non-warp methods of instantaneous travel, but I'm going to try and list them. In your answer you can provide a better list:

- Star Trek Discovery - *[Context Is For Kings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings_(episode))* - [Spore Drive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spore_drive)
- Star Trek TNG - *[Encounter At Farpoint](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode))*  - Q travelling via the [Q continuum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_Continuum)
- Star Trek TNG - *[Contagion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Contagion_(episode))* - [Iconian Gateway](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Iconian_gateway)
- Star Trek TNG - *[The Nth Degree](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nth_Degree_(episode))* - [Subspace Inversion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Subspace_distortion)
- Star Trek Voyager - *[Threshold](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode))* - [Infinite Warp](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Warp_10)
- Star Trek TNG - *[A Matter of Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Matter_of_Time_(episode))* - [Wormholes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wormhole)
- Star Trek TNG - *[When the Bough Breaks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/When_The_Bough_Breaks_(episode))* - Aldean [Repulsor Beam](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Repulsor_beam)
- Star Trek TNG - *[Where No One Has Gone Before](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_No_One_Has_Gone_Before_(episode))* - [Traveller's Thoughts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Traveler)
- Star Trek TOS - *[That Which Survives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Which_Survives)* - [Matter Anti-Matter Integrator Fusion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/That_Which_Survives_(episode))
- Star Trek ENT - *[Carpenter St](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Carpenter_Street_(episode))* - [31st Century Time Travel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_travel)

My question is: **What are all the forms of instantaneous galactic travel in the Star Trek Universe?**

Comment: [*Is* the spore drive instantaneous?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171397/is-the-spore-drive-instantaneous)

Comment: I believe you've listed all of them..

Comment: Geodesic Fold if the crew doesn't have to survive, Spatial Flexure, Spatial Trajector, whatever Kes did...  There's quite a few in Voyager

Comment: You have listed basically all of them. Why don't you take off the list from the question and put it in a proper answer? With a brief description of each one it would be a great answer.

Comment: Many of these are non instantaneous.

Comment: Where does instantaneous travel through a wormhole occur in *A Matter of Time*? And in *Carpenter St.*? I am not sure classifying "time travel" as "instantaneous" makes any sense in the first place, but if you include travel through time, not just from place to place, there should be earlier examples than *Carpenter St.*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>***Disclaimers:*** Your question lists many of the known forms of "instantaneous" travel, so I won't cover them here if you want to add your own answer; if you want me to include them, please state this in a comment here. Also, I am interpreting "instantaneous" as "amazingly faster than warp speeds", because to be really instantaneous it should be infinite speed, so only the Infinite Warp from Voyager would apply, IMHO.</sub>

---

## Star Trek: Deep Space Nine

- **[The Bajoran Wormhole](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran_wormhole):** it was the only known stable Wormhole of the Galaxy, and connected two points distant about 70,000 light years from each other; it would have taken slightly less than 70 years to a Federation starship to cross the same space, but through the Wormhole the voyage was *nearly* instantaneous.

## Star Trek: Voyager

- **[The Caretaker's Array](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Caretaker%27s_array):** this space station was located in the Delta Quadrant, about 75,000 light years from Federation Space. It transported several ships from the Badlands in the Alpha Quadrant to its location. The station was operated by a [Nacene](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nacene), and it is unclear if the ultra-fast transport was caused by advanced technology or by the inherent nature and powers of this species.
- **[Quantum Slipstream Drive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quantum_slipstream_drive):** an advanced form of propulsion technology discovered by *USS Voyager* and developed by a species native to the Delta Quadrant. It used a quantum field to allow the whole ship to penetrate subspace and exceed its maximum warp speeds.
- **[Borg Transwarp Network](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transwarp_hub):** it was a network of [transwarp corridors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transwarp_conduit) operated by the Borg; it was a transwarp and tachyon based technology.
- **[Vaadwaur's "Underspace"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Underspace):** a network of subspace corridors, allowing starships to traverse vast distances in a short time.
- **[Tash's_catapult](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tash%27s_catapult):** a massive device that used a graviton field to "catapult" a ship though distances not normally covered with standard ship drives.
- **[Nyrian Translocator](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Translocator):** a transporter-like device with a range of over ten light years, used to [steal equipment and personnel off Voyager](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Displaced_(episode)).
- **[Sikarian Spacial Trajector](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spatial_trajector)** a space-folding device which instantly relocated objects to any place within 40,000 light years.

Comment: Great - is it worth adding the ones from @Izkata above from Voyager ?

Comment: I did not want to "steal" from others, pretty much the same reason what I have not included what you listed in your question; I will let some time pass the let the original proposers add their own answers if they wish to do so, then I will consider add them here.

Comment: In *Voyager*, there's also the [Spatial Projector](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Spatial_trajector) from the episode "[Prime Factors](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Prime_Factors_(episode))". The Sikarians developed it, who are also native to the Delta Quadrant.